# standard aurelia template referencing file outside src directory

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I have created a new aurelia project via `au new` and have no issues referencing typescript files in the `src` folder. For example in `main.ts` this works:

main.ts

```
import { Util } from './util';  //in aurelia-app\src
new Util();
```

util.ts

```
export class Util{ }
```

When I move util.ts up one level, this breaks the `au` CLI:

```
import { Util } from '../util'; //in aurelia-app\
```

Error:

> Tracing main...  ------- File not found or not accessible ------
>   | Location: D:/temp/aurelia-test1/aurelia-app/util.js
>   | Requested by:> D:/temp/aurelia-test1/aurelia-app/src/main.js
>   | Is this a package?
>   Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a
>   Node.js package

Can someone tell me why the CLI doesn't like this and possibly how to fix it ?

There is a clue insofar as the log states its looking for `util.js` however this doesnt explain why it *does* work when `util.ts` is in the `src` folder because i do not see `util.js` in this folder either.

### update

As per @Jesse answer below you can modify `aurelia.json` to fix the problem as stated above - however this fails if you want to go another directory higher. For example

```
import { Util } from '../../util';
```

Comment: As per the updated question, you're referencing files outside your project. These are (obviously) not transpiled. If you wish to reference external files, I'd look into using npm packages or maybe Aurelia plugins.

Comment: why are they 'obviously' not transpiled? nb, i have updated the `source` value in `aurelia.json` to point to ts files outside the project dir

Comment: Because your Aurelia project runs in your `/aurelia-app` folder. The CLI won't look for files outside the project to transpile. You could try tampering with the `"baseDir"`-setting in your `aurelia.json` but if you want to import external files, I'd recommend asking a different question about that.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your `aurelia.json` is configured to transpile all `.ts` files in the `src`-folder:

```
"transpiler": {
    "id": "typescript",
    "displayName": "TypeScript",
    "fileExtension": ".ts",
    "dtsSource": [
      "./custom_typings/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "source": "src/**/*.ts" <--- right here
 },
```

Therefore it won't transpile your typescript file in the root. You can change the transpiler settings in the `aurelia.json` to overcome this, but I'd recommend keeping your typescript in the `src`-folder.

Comment: out of curiosity, does the CLI write the js to disk as individual files or is it piped directly for bundling ?

Comment: good question, I'm not quite sure, perhaps some of the Aurelia core members can shine some more confident light on this.

Comment: how do you handle referencing shared js/ts file(s) from other projects ? e.g. in my case I have a `common-lib` project and I want to reference a specific class from there

Comment: btw Jesse your solution *does* work as per my example above but for some reason if you reference a level higher then things stop working again - i will update my q to reflect this